# Saving table state for extendedDataTable in RichFaces 4.0

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, richfaces, horizontal-scrolling

In Richfaces 3.3, extendedDataTable had attribute "tableState" which was used to save the state of table sorting, column width, column order, etc in backing bean string variable but in RichFaces 4.0, this do not seem to be there. Is it still under implementation? or I can perform the same action in different manner?

Migration guide do not suggest anything and is hardly helpful in case of extendedDataTable.

I am facing lots of issues with horizontal scrolling as well. Horizontal scrollbar disappears, if I extend width of column by somewidth. This is replicable on richfaces demo site as well. Just extend any column width by few pixels and horizontal scroll disappears.

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=extendedDataTable

Has anyone tried extendedDataTable of RF4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is not yet implemented for RF4.0. Tentatively planned for 4.3.0. 
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-10442